# $.notify is not a function using typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, notifications

I am trying to integrate notification module in my application as a reference posted here - https://github.com/bonnici/light-bootstrap-dashboard-angularcli

Build:Property 'notify' does not exist on type 'JQueryStatic'.

**Here is my notification.service.ts file looks like**

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


 export enum NotificationType {
Info = 1,
Success,
Warning,
Danger
 }

 export class NotificationOptions {
public message: string;
public icon: string = null;
public timer = 4000;
public type: NotificationType = NotificationType.Info;
public from = 'top';
public align = 'right';

public constructor(
    fields: {
        message: string,
        icon?: string,
        timer?: number,
        type?: NotificationType,
        from?: string,
        align?: string
    }) {

    this.message = fields.message;
    this.icon = fields.icon || this.icon;
    this.timer = fields.timer || this.timer;
    this.type = fields.type || this.type;
    this.from = fields.from || this.from;
    this.align = fields.align || this.align;
     }
  }

    @Injectable()
    export class NotificationService {

constructor() { }

public notify(options: NotificationOptions): void {
    let typeString;
    switch (options.type) {
        case NotificationType.Success:
            typeString = 'success';
            break;
        case NotificationType.Warning:
            typeString = 'warning';
            break;
        case NotificationType.Danger:
            typeString = 'danger';
            break;
        default:
            typeString = 'info';
            break;
    }

    $.notify(
        {
            icon: options.icon,
            message: options.message
        },
        {
            type: typeString,
            timer: options.timer,
            placement: {
                from: options.from,
                align: options.align
            }
        });
         }
  }
```

**In my .component.ts file, i am calling like below**

```
    import { NotificationService, NotificationOptions }      from '../../shared/services/notification.service';
   constructor(private notificationService: NotificationService) { }

     ngOnInit(): void {
    this.notificationService.notify(new NotificationOptions({
        message: 'Welcome!',
        icon: 'pe-7s-gift'
    }));
    }
```

But, during compilation i m getting error at $.notify function as below in my VS2015

- Property 'notify' does not exists on type 'JqueryStatic'
- Symbol notify cannot be properly resolved, probably it is located in    inaccessible module

when i user ($ as any).notify the exception was gone from VS compilation. But, page is throwing an error $.notify is not a function.

Any help here?

Comment: Are you trying to use `deferred.progress()` and `deferred.notify()`?

Comment: No, I am not. The sample in my question is working fine in visual studio code. Whereas it's not working when I plug it specific notification component and integrating to my application in visual studio2015. Another difference i noticed was, I am using jquery 2+ version. Whereas sample was using 1.x version. I am new to angular2 and using jquery. Not sure why this is not working.

Comment: I changed to use $.deferred.notify() and both UX & VS2015 compilation issues are gone. But, the notification is not showing in the page and there are no console errors as well.

Answer (score 0):

> But, page is throwing an error $.notify is not a function.

Make sure the bootstrap javascript is loaded after the jquery javascript.

## More

Bootstrap docs : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

Comment: I am able to resolve the build compilation only after using ($ as any).notify. After that, I am seeing the error in if As notify is not a function.

Comment: I didn't understand your statement of loading bootstrap js after jquery js.